# Counting nodes for each index + toString

Tags: java, hashmap

So I was wondering if there is a way to print out which index of the list has the most collisions? As well as this, I wanted to know, what is the best way to produce a toString() for my LinkedList? I've tried a few times with the default implementation for a LinkedList toString but I can't quite figure out how to do it.

Thanks in advance!

Code:

```
static LinkedList<Node> hashTable[] = new LinkedList[100];

static class Node {
    int value;
    int key;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Value: " + value + " " + "Key: " + key;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    File f = new File("Ex5.txt");

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(f);

    if (f.exists() == false) {
        System.out.println("File doesn't exist or could not be found.");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        hashTable[i] = null;
    }

    while (scan.hasNextInt()) {
        int n = scan.nextInt();
        insert(n, hashFunction(n));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        System.out.println(hashTable[i]);
    }

    int emptyEntries = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        if (hashTable[i] == null) {
            emptyEntries += 1;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Number of empty entries: " + emptyEntries);
}

public static void insert(int key, int value) {
    int index = hashFunction(value);
    LinkedList<Node> items = hashTable[index];

    if (items == null) {
        items = new LinkedList<>();

        Node item = new Node();
        item.key = key;
        item.value = value;

        items.add(item);

        hashTable[index] = items;
    } else {
        for (Node item : items) {
            if (item.key == key) {
                item.value = value;
                return;
            }
        }

        Node item = new Node();
        item.key = key;
        item.value = value;

        items.add(item);
    }
}

public static int hashFunction(int value) {
    int hashKey = value % 100;
    return hashKey;
}
```

Comment: You are using a LinkedList as a HashTable when Hashtables exist. Why?

Comment: Requirements of my assignment, I can't use any libraries except for LinkedList + the file opener/reader, should've mentioned that sorry.

Comment: `File f = new File("Ex5.txt");` you attempt to read this empty file immediately after creation. You will get no input.

Comment: Ohh I forgot, it's on my computer, but it's just one random int on each line for 100 lines. If you wanted to test the code you could do less lines, same effect.

Comment: Next time, please add more comments to your code to highlight which sections of code are responsible for important tasks for the question. Personally, it was very hard for me to understand your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Classes are objects. LinkedList is a class. All objects extend java.lang.Object and you can always call `Object.toString()` on them, but what you are likely looking for is a way to print out all the values. In this case, it is best to use a for loop:

```java
for(int i=0; i<items.size(); i++){
    System.out.println(items.get(i));
}
```

You are printing multiple lines, each containing various amounts of `Node` objects. You want to find which line has the most amounts of Node objects.

The way to do this is simple. You need nested for loops to print that, and thus you can do this, with your for loops

```java
int maxNodes = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
int index = -1;
for(int i=0; i<LinkedList.size(); i++){
    int nodes = 0;
    for(int j=0; j<nestedLinkedList.size(); j++){
        System.out.print(NodeInformation);
        nodes++;
    }
    if(nodes>maxNodes){
        index = i;
        maxNodes = nodes;
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

This sample code would find which line would contain the most Node objects.

Comment: That's not quite what I was looking for, I need to find which index of hashTable[] possess the most collisions as well a show many it is. Adding to that, I think Object.toString doesn't work because I have to print array instances rather than objects. The values still print weirdly.

Comment: First, (your words with 0 alterations) `As well as this, I wanted to know, what is the best way to produce a toString() for my LinkedList?` What do you mean by collisions? How exactly do I find a collision with the information from your code?

Comment: If the code I originally posted is run  then the array will be printed, on each line there's multiple nodes and I need to find a way to print/find which one has the most nodes on it. Update: I managed to get the toString() to work  by implementing it for the node itself. Missed that idea lol.